# Multivariate test with a html5 mobile app

Tags: android, ios, html, web-applications, multivariate-testing

What is the best strategy to implement a html5 based mobile app for iOS / Android that can allow multivariate testing? Is it a good idea to have the html A/B files on the server and deliver them on-demand or is there a better strategy to avoid resending the app to the Apple's review team?

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers of a HTML5 multivariate testing framework called xander.  For mobile apps, IMO it's best to bake the variants in with your app.  App updates can be issued for new or changed variants.  This can avoid the slowness of server calls.

Our github is here:
https://github.com/255BITS/xander

The xander.io service is here:
http://xander.io